# C++ compiler error with string and int parameters

Tags: c++, windows, parameters, compiler-errors, type-conversion

I'm using codeblocks for c++ on windows (with MinGW's GCC compiler) with a simple function...

```
void foo(string line, int lineno); //declaration = LINE_B
void foo(string line, int lineno){ //function body
    if(lineno==1){//actions}
    elseif(lineno==2){//actions}
    //etc
}
//call to function inside main = LINE_A
foo(str, i); //where str and i are initialized earlier
```

but the program won't compile with these two errors listed for that function...
LINE_A error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int* (*)()' [-fpermissive]
LINE_B error: initializing argument 2 of 'void foo(std::string, int* (*)())' [-fpermissive]
what's going on?
side note, the program compiles/runs without issue on mac os x with g++

Comment: put the complete code!

Comment: @JerryGoyal for the program, or the function?

Comment: for complete program as your function seems to be correct.

Comment: the program is 400 lines, but those are the only 2 errors

Comment: paste your code on ideone.com and share the link. there is something wrong with the arguments

Answer (score 0):

The following code compiles properly on my machine:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void foo( string line, int lineno ); //declaration = LINE_B
void foo( string line, int lineno )
{
    //function body
    if ( lineno == 1 )
    {
        //actions
    }
    else if ( lineno == 2 )
    {
        //actions}
        //etc
    }
}

int main()
{
    string s{};
    int i{};
    foo( s, i );
    char c; cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Andrew Please don't type code or data/results. Copy/paste. No-one wants to chase typos before even getting to your problem.